# How to delete a textInput upon a radioButtons click in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

the task I face is to create a reactive text input form. Depending on the value chosen by a radio button either one or two textInput fields shall be displayed. So far so good. But when changing from 2 text inputs to one, the value of the second input is preseved. I tried to delete the textInput values with the `observe()` but it didn't work as expected. This is the code I use:

```
#library(shiny)
if (interactive()) {

  ui <- fluidPage(
    radioButtons("controller", "No. inputs", choices = c(1, 2), selected = 2),
    uiOutput("text_fields"),
    verbatimTextOutput("test")
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$text_fields <- renderUI({  
      if(input$controller == 2){
        fluidRow(
          column(6, textInput("inText_1", label = "Input text 1", value = "")),
          column(6, textInput("inText_2", label = "Input text 2", value = ""))
        )
      }else{
        fluidRow(textInput("inText_1", label = "Input text 1", value = ""))
      }
    })

    output$test <- renderText(c(input$inText_1, input$inText_2))

    observe({
      # The input$controller variable needs to be used inside the observe, correct?
      x <- input$controller

      # This will delete the values of text input, based on change of x
      updateTextInput(session, "inText_1", value = "")
      updateTextInput(session, "inText_2", value = "")
    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

The following two pictures show my problem:
1. Start with two inputs "Hello" and "World"
[image]

2. Now after clicking on radio button value 1 to get only one textInput, the "Hello" is gone but the "World" still exists (which I usually would say is a good thing, but right now I'd rather delete it):
   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good case for using a `conditionalPanel`:

```
library(shiny)
if (interactive()) {

    ui <- fluidPage(
        radioButtons("controller", "No. inputs", choices = c(1, 2), selected = 2),
        fluidRow(
            column(6, textInput("inText_1", "Input text 1", value = "")),
            column(6, conditionalPanel('input.controller == 2',
               textInput("inText_2", "Input text 2", value = "")))
        ),
        verbatimTextOutput("test")
    )

    server <- function(input, output, session) {

        output$test <- renderText(c(input$inText_1, input$inText_2))

        observe({
            # The input$controller variable needs to be used inside the observe, correct?
            x <- input$controller

            # This will delete the values of text input, based on change of x
            updateTextInput(session, "inText_1", value = "")
            updateTextInput(session, "inText_2", value = "")
        })

    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```